# Linux C Network communication program works in debugger but not outside

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have two files, server.c and client.c. The server listens for a client request and then replies appropriately (right now just LIST with a static directory is implemented). When the server receives the LIST command, it counts the amount of regular files in the directory specified (which is a static value right now), then sends the client the amount so that it keeps listening until n elements have been received. The server then starts sending the file names to the listening client.

This works in theory and when debugging the server but not when I am running both applications normally through the terminal. The client just gets stuck after typing in the LIST command and while the server receives it, it does not continue with sending the amount of items and the names. When, however, running the server in debugging mode in CodeBlocks (though I guess IDE does not matter) and going through the code line by line, everything works exactly as intended. It may be some sort of race condition, but I am unable to resolve it on my own.

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF 1024
#define PORT 8543

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int create_socket;
  char buffer[BUF];
  struct sockaddr_in address;
  int size;

  if ((create_socket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
     perror("Socket error");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  memset(&address,0,sizeof(address));
  address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_port = htons (PORT);
  const char *addr = "localhost";
  inet_aton (addr, &address.sin_addr);
  if (connect ( create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof (address)) == 0)
  {
     printf ("Connection with server (%s) established\n", inet_ntoa (address.sin_addr));
     size=recv(create_socket,buffer,BUF-1, 0);
    if (size>0)
     {
        buffer[size]= '\0';
        printf("%s",buffer);
        bzero(buffer, BUF);

     }
  }
  else
  {
     perror("Connect error - no server available");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  do {
     printf ("Send message: ");
     fgets (buffer, BUF, stdin);
     send(create_socket, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
     if(strcmp(buffer, "LIST\n")){
        bzero(buffer, BUF);
        size=recv(create_socket,buffer,BUF-1, 0);
        if(size >0){
          buffer[size] = '\0';
          int items = atoi(buffer);
         printf("%d", items);
          bzero(buffer, BUF);
          for(int i = 0; i < items; i++){
            size=recv(create_socket,buffer,BUF-1, 0);
            if(size >0){
              buffer[size] = '\0';
              printf("%s\n", buffer);
            }
            bzero(buffer, BUF);
          }
        }
     }
  }
  while (strcmp (buffer, "QUIT\n") != 0);
  close (create_socket);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#define BUF 1024
#define PORT 8543

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
  int create_socket, new_socket;
  socklen_t addrlen;
  char buffer[BUF];
  int size;
  struct sockaddr_in address, cliaddress;
  struct dirent *direntp;
  DIR *dirp;

  create_socket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  memset(&address,0,sizeof(address));
  address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  address.sin_port = htons (PORT);

  int yes = 1;
  if (setsockopt(create_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
  }


  if (bind ( create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof (address)) != 0) {
     perror("bind error");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  listen (create_socket, 5);

  addrlen = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);

  int file_count = 0;
  struct dirent * entry;

  dirp = opendir("/home"); 
  while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
    /* Only increment counter if item selected is a regular file */
    if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) {
         file_count++;
    }
  }
  closedir(dirp);

  while (1) {
     printf("Waiting for connections...\n");
     new_socket = accept ( create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddress, &addrlen );
     if (new_socket > 0)
    {
        printf ("Client connected from %s:%d...\n", inet_ntoa (cliaddress.sin_addr),ntohs(cliaddress.sin_port));
        strcpy(buffer,"Welcome, please enter your command:\n");
        send(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer),0);
        bzero(buffer, BUF);
     }
     do {
        size = recv (new_socket, buffer, BUF-1, 0);
        if( size > 0)
        {
           if(strcmp(buffer, "LIST\n") == 0){
              if ((dirp = opendir("/home")) == NULL) {
                perror ("Failed to open directory");
                return 1;
              }
              bzero(buffer, BUF);
              sprintf(buffer, "%d", file_count);
              /* Send client the amount of items he is to receive */
              send(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer),0);
              bzero(buffer, BUF);
              while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
                  /* Check if item is a file and if yes, send client its name */
                  if (direntp->d_type == DT_REG){
                    strcpy(buffer,direntp->d_name);
                    send(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer),0);
                    bzero(buffer, BUF);
                  }
              while ((closedir(dirp) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) ;
           }
        }
        else if (size == 0)
        {
           printf("Client closed remote socket\n");
           break;
        }
        else
        {
           perror("recv error");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
     } while (strncmp (buffer, "quit", 4)  != 0);
     close (new_socket);
  }
  close (create_socket);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You know that if the server calls `send` twice, the client might still get both parts of the data in one `recv` call?

Comment: Don't recv and send block? By the time the server sends the data of the second send call, the client should already be waiting for this specific reply.

Comment: recv blocks if there is nothing to receive, send blocks if the send buffer is full (which means the client is not calling recv).

Comment: TCP treats your data as a single stream of bytes. Kinda like a file - if you make two calls to `fwrite` then you'll still read all that data in one call to `fread` if you try to.

Comment: You guys were right, I debugged the client and noticed that in addition to the amount of items, the buffer also already contained the names of few files. Any idea on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

As [immibis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/immibis) pointed out, your code assumes that each individual `send` corresponds to an individual `recv`. When you **slowly** step through the code, this assumption turns out to be (accidentally) correct, but when the program runs, multiple `send`s can be read by a single `recv`.

This is a very common mistake. Thing is, TCP works with streams of data, not individual packets or messages. It's just like reading or writing data to/from a file (as [immibis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/immibis) pointed out). The `send` call puts data in the send buffer, and TCP can decide for itself when to send it. The timing of the arrival at the receiving end depends on when the data was sent and on (often unpredictable) network conditions.

The solution is to divide the data stream into chunks (messages) **yourself**. Here are a few ways of doing that:

- Use fixed length messages - if all messages have a fixed length, the receiver just has to `recv` the right number of bytes. If there's anything left in the receive buffer after those bytes, then that data already belongs to the next message.
- Send the length of the message before each message. If you want to send the string "blah", encode it as "0004blah" or something similar. The receiver will always read the first four bytes (which are 0004) to figure out the number of remaining bytes to read. It will then read the required number of bytes, process the message, and then wait for the next one. It's a robust solution that's also easy to implement.
- Use a delimiter. Lines in text files are divided by newline characters (`\n`). Similarly, you can add a special delimiter byte (or bytes) between messages. For example, you can define that messages always end with a dollar sign ($). Then all the receiver has to do is `recv` from the socket byte by byte until it receives a dollar sign. Of course if you take this approach, you have to make sure that the body of the messages doesn't contain the delimiter character.